# ui-router for manual parsing URL without using views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ngroute

I want to watch a location and run a function when the location changes.
I also want to be able to easily change locations by running a function.
I want to be able to use the browser back buttons.

Sound like a good mission for `ngRoute` or `ui-router`

No.

I don't need views, templates, and controller.

I want the power of `ui-router` and `ngRoute` for parsing URL's and get the `stateParams`.

**In other words:** How to use routes in `angular` without  using views, templates, or  controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds what you need is just the `$location` service. You can use it without `ngRoute` or `ui-route`.

> ### The `$location` Service. What does it do?
>
> The `$location` service parses the URL in the browser address bar (based on window.location) and makes the URL available to your application. Changes to the URL in the address bar are reflected into the `$location` service and changes to `$location` are reflected into the browser address bar.
>
> The `$location` service:
>
> - Exposes the current URL in the browser address bar, so you can
>
>   - Watch and observe the URL.
>   - Change the URL.
> - Maintains synchronization between itself and the browser's URL when the user
>
>   - Changes the address in the browser's address bar.
>   - Clicks the back or forward button in the browser (or clicks a History link).
>   - Clicks on a link in the page.
> - Represents the URL object as a set of methods (protocol, host, port, path, search, hash).

-- [AngularJS Developer Guide -- Using `$location`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

> ### Events
>
> ### `$locationChangeStart`
>
> Broadcasted before a URL will change.
>
> ### `$locationChangeSuccess`
>
> Broadcasted after a URL was changed.

-- [AngularJS $location Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

You can use the `$location` service without either the Angular router or the Angular-UI router. In fact you can use it if you want to roll your own router.

Comment: Do I need to do anything to make $location to start sending event, or it will always do it by itself?

Comment: You need to inject somewhere. The AngularJS does lazy loading of services but once loaded it will broadcast to $rootScope. And you **can** load it in a run block.

Comment: If I do this `app.run(function ($location){})`, it will start fire those events?

Comment: Thank's. I always prefer less dependencies

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is your setup is, but if you control all the routes and they are rather limited, then you can try to add the "abstract" states, they don't need a view or a controller. I think that by the way this is not required for ordinary states either, but not 100% sure.

Perhaps if you define the abstract route for the top of your application, then you will get events for all "theoretical" children.

You can find an example of abstract state [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views#user-content-abstract-states)

```
$stateProvider
    .state('contacts', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/contacts',
    })
```

Now if you will go to /contacts you should get the event of stateChange, and I think you will get it if you will go to /contacts/something as well. In the worst case you might define you whole application as a tree of this parent/child states that are all abstract.

To handle the event you need to do this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState){ 
    var greeting = toState.data.customData1 + " " + toState.data.customData2;
    console.log(greeting);
```

Comment: Can you provide some code. I really not understand what do you mean add "abstract" states. My app not uses routes right now

Comment: This is not possible to do in the ngRoute as far as I know, only available in ui-router.

Comment: I see your edit. But where I need my function to be run, when user navigate to this `abstract state`. Maybe I can use `events`. How can I notify my app that the user change the state?

Comment: There is a stateChangeStart and stateChangeSuccess events that you can handle. I have added the example to the answer, but it's also in the same documentation. You just have to play around a bit to see how these events are generated with abstract states and nested states, so you should be able to utilize it's power without controllers and views

Comment: Thank's. I'm upvote. It seems that you didn't have use it before, or you not sure that it's gonna work. Waiting to see if someone else did it before. If not, I will accept your answer.
Thank's alot

Comment: I have used abstract and nested states, and they all work fine, but I have never tried to use them only for the routing without controllers and views as you need :) I use the events to intercept and change the url (e..g for authentication) - it works very well. But you need to try for yourself to see how it will work with your needs. (unless someone else has a better idea :))